# ILMerge and MSBuild - merged EXE is giving runtime error

Tags: msbuild, ilmerge

After adding ILMerge to my post build tasks and working out the commandline, I sucessfully get a merged program MyMerged.exe

But when I run it, I get an exception

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: 
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskItem' from assembly 'mymerged, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '.ctor' has no implementation (no RVA).
   at MyProgram.Program.Main(String[] args)

Is this a bug in ILMerge not handling a situation where there is no constructor, or a bug in TaskItem for not having one.

thanks

Comment: Found a better way.... See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Include `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll` on the ILMerge command line so that it will get merged in with your assembly and found.

If you have duplicate types defined and use the `/allowDup` command line switch, ILMerge will rename the duplicate types and this may also cause "Could not load type ..." errors and unexpected behavior during runtime, especially when reflection is being used.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thw part about /allowDup was really helpful, thanks! instead of this part "/allowDup MyMainDLL.dll <star>.dll" just used "<star>.dll"